# Facing issue while creating wear App XML : AAPT: error: attribute android:boxedEdges not found

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

In the below XML, I am getting error over `android:boxedEdges="all"`. I have tried to remove this line but not solved it.

I am still getting the AAPT: error: attribute android:boxedEdges not found

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_grey"
        android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:deviceIds="wear">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
            android:boxedEdges="all">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Press Here" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

This is a simple wear OS project. I am new on that so any help or link will appreciates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `app:boxedEdges`, not `android:boxedEdges` as per the [BoxInsetLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts#same-layout).